# Track event changes using Delta query in Security Alerts (Microsoft Graph API)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft.Graph library in .NET Core 3. I have a problem regarding change tracking using deltas. Suppose

I want to get changes via delta query using something like the code below:
ISecurityAlertsCollectionRequest page;

```
            var page = await graphClient.Security.Alerts
                                    .Delta()
                                    .Request()
                                    .GetAsync();
```

but it does not work. Which is the propper/correct way to get changes (alert details: like hostname, ipAddress etc.) via delta query in MS Graph. I red all the documentation about webhooks but I did not found any example or documentation related to delta queries for Security API changes. How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Delta queries for Security API are not supported. Please raise the [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests)